# Why can't I send a message from client to server using sockets.io?

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io

Here is my client function:

```
var socket = io();
socket.on('connection', function(data) {
io.socket.emit('clientMessage', 'client message');
})
```

Here is my server code:

```
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
            socket.on('clientMessage', function (msg) {
                console.log(msg);
            });
        });
```

But this seems to be broken since nothing is being emitted to the server. How Do I fix this? Thank you so much.

Comment: @RolandStarke so I can't send to the server?

Comment: @apsillers thank you socket.emit worked perfectly

Comment: @apsillers - If you don't want for the `connect` event on the client, your `socket.emit()` may be lost in some circumstances.  You can see my answer for the proper way to wait for the connection to happen.

Comment: If @jfriend00's answer below solved your issue, you should click the check mark to mark your problem as resolved. (You may wish to do this for some of your past questions as well, if they are solved.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The client function should be this:

```
var socket = io();
socket.on('connect', function() {
    socket.emit('clientMessage', 'client message');
});
```

There are two separate issues in the client:

1. On the client side, the event is `connect`, not `connection`.
2. You should do `socket.emit()`, not `io.socket.emit()`.

Comment: @predator44 - Did this answer your question?

Comment: I thought I selected it, my bad. thank you for your help